# How to print the required output with the help of SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

I have tables 'users' and 'user_transactions' in AWS Athena. The table has many columns but I am interested in 2 columns viz. `user name` and `txn_type`.

The `txn_type` column has 3 possible values viz. `FT, NFT, PT`.

For each user, I need to print the count of each transactions in the below format.
The output should contain 4 columns with userId, and count of each txns.

```
User Name, CountOfTxns of type FT, CountOfTxns of type NFT, CountOfTxns of type PT
```

Morover, I need to join user and user_transactions table for printing records of users who are of type = 'Gold'

so to find the users, it will be

```
select userId, userName from users, user_transactions t where u.userId = t=userId and u.type = 'Gold';
```

Then for these users, I need to print the output with 4 columns as described above.

So if a user with name = 'ABC' and Id = 1 and user_type = 'Gold' has 3 counts of FT, 5 counts of NFT and 0 counts of PT,

and if a user with name = 'XYZ' and Id = 2 and user_type = 'Gold' has 9 counts of FT, 0 counts of NFT and 45 counts of PT, the output should be
the output should be

```
User Name, CountOfTxns of type FT, CountOfTxns of type NFT, CountOfTxns of type PT

ABC, 3, 5, 0
XYZ, 9, 0, 45
```

How can I write a query which can print all counts in a single row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate each field individually like so:

```
   SELECT u.name,
      SUM(CASE WHEN t.txn_type = 'FT' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as FT_count,
      SUM(CASE WHEN t.txn_type = 'NFT' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as NFT_count,
      SUM(CASE WHEN t.txn_type = 'PT' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as PT_count
    FROM users u, transactions t
    WHERE u.user_id = t.user_id and u.type = 'Gold'
    GROUP BY u.name;
```